# Rails 3.2 - Recieving a weird error when trying to edit a new database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I have an object called `Job` that belong to another object
called `client` in a many relationship.

Here's my job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Here's my Client model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :jobs
end
```

For a new job, I simply want to assign it during creation to a client.

When I try to create a new job however. All im seeing in my view is the id of the job instead of the name and the internals of the created model are also empty.

When I try to edit the job and save it again im recieving the following error.

```
Client(#2157214400) expected, got String(#2151988620)

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:61:in `block in update'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

I guess this could be because my controller is wrong in some way but this is my first app so im not quite sure where to look.

Here's my controller.

class JobsController < ApplicationController

```
    def index
      @job = Job.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @job }
      end
    end

    def show
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @job }
      end
    end

    def new
      @job = Job.new(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @job }
      end
    end

    def edit
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @job = Job.new(params[:jobs])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @job.save
          format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'job was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
          format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'job was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
      @job.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :jobs }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any pointers or a nod in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the form for editing your Job.

Comment: The form is long to post here but it's here.. https://gist.github.com/2638538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because Activerecord expected an instance of Client object , and it has method client= (because belogs_to association) 
When you bind AR object from request you should use client_id parameter instead of client

you can read about http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

if client count is short you can use select with client_id as name 
Example http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

so you can do something like that

```
select("job", "client_id", Client.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})
```

instead of

```
 f.text_field :client, :class => 'text_field'
```

Comment: Thank you.. where do I need to specify that?

Comment: I entered that text as you said in my view but all im seeing is that text and now a input box.

Comment: input box  contain all existing clients , so when you create job, you must select needed client from it